# Sketching graphs in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to sketch the graph of the function on the interval $ t>= 0 $

$ f(t)=u_1(t)+2u_3(t)-6u_4(t) $

not quite sure how to work through this practice problem

I see that it starts at 1, then jumps up 1, then jumps down 8 but not quite sure how to represent this

Comment: are the functions $u_1$ to $u_4$ known?

Comment: @JEET TRIVEDI no they are not

Comment: Is there any other information given? Initial values?

Comment: nope just on the interval t>=0